# Java applet pane movable by arrow keys?

Tags: java

How can I make my java applet unlimited or set to a certain size where I can move the thing (not the window) with the arrow keys and the images
And stuff will stay in place?

Comment: Hi can you please rephrase your question? It is very short and doesn't  give enough information to understand what you really want to do.  Perhaps include simple diagrams this will help people give you a better answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyListeners to do this task. Like this :-

```
class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        switch (e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            leftKey = true;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            rightKey = true;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            upKey = true;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            downKey = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        switch (e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            leftKey = false;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            rightKey = false;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            upKey = false;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            downKey = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is only a way how can you use the KeyListner and events. You can do it in your way.

Comment: But, how can I make it so the thing moves free? Like In a game you move around the map with the arrow keys? Like that basically

Comment: Add Listeners to the particular object which you you want to make movable from ARROW KEYS